# glob() Multiple files have the same file name with different file extensions

Tags: php

Multiple files have the same file name with different file extensions

**Files:**

- media/

  - name.jpg
  - name.png
  - name.gif
  - name2.png

Find files with the same name and get array with extensions:

```php
   $file = null;
   $file = glob('*/*/media/name.*');
   rsort($file);
   echo'<pre>'; print_r($file); echo'</pre>';
```

expected:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => jpg
    [1] => png
    [2] => gif
)
```

unexpected:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => media/name.jpg
    [1] => media/name.png
    [2] => media/name.gif
)
```

Comment: yes that is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Glob function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

```
$name= "hello";

$files = glob("/path/to/files/$name.*"); // Will find all file with hello.extension

if (count($files) > 0){
foreach ($files as $file)
 {
    $info = pathinfo($file);
    echo "File found: extension ".$info["extension"]."<br>";
 }
 }else{
  echo "No file name exists called $name."
}
```